# n- dimensional normed linear space isomorphic to n-dimensional Euclidean space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is an n- dimensional normed linear space over R. Is it isomorphic to n-dimensional Euclidean space $R^n$. I know it is topologically isomorphic but what about isometry? I think if it is an inner product space then by considering some orthonormal basis we can have inner product space isomorphism but not with normed linear space structure. Am I correct?

Comment: I am asking the converse. I know they are linearly isomorphic but do we have isometric isomorphism?

Comment: No, the spaces are not isometrically isomorphic. For instance, $({\mathbb R}^n, \| \cdot\|_2)$ and $({\mathbb R}^n, \| \cdot\|_p)$, where $1\leq p\ne 2 \leq \infty$, are not isometrically isomorphic.

Comment: How to show it?

Comment: I think if we take inner product space then it is inner product space isomorphic.

Comment: Try to see what is going on in the case of ${\mathbb R}^2$.

Comment: Related to my previous comment: consider unit balls in $\| \cdot\|_p$ norms for different $p$ (the case ${\mathbb R}^2$ is enough).

Comment: Exactly as you say, isometric isomorphism would preserve [parallelogram law](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/norms-induced-by-inner-products-and-the-parallelogram-law). This should help you to show that, for example, $(\mathbb R^2,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and $(\mathbb R^2,\|\cdot\|_2)$ are not isometrically isomorphic. (And, additionaly, only one of them is an inner product space.)

Comment: About finitely dimensional inner product spaces: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/why-is-it-true-that-every-finite-dimensional-inner-product-space-is-a-hilbert-sp

Comment: [this paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/links/ea15962f35a2f04fe1167b25167b4f88/aa589.pdf) could be interesting to you