# Prob. 3, Sec. 3.2 in Kreyszig's Functional Analysis Book: Is the space of all polynomials of a fixed degree complete?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, inner-products

Let $n$ be a given natural number, and let $X$ denote the vector space consisting of the zero polynomial and of all  polynomials of degree at most  $n$, with real or complex numbers as co-efficients, and defined on a given closed interval $[a,b]$ of the real line, with the inner product defined by 
$$\langle x, y \rangle \ \colon= \  \int_a^b \ x(t) \ \overline{y(t) } \ \mathrm{d} t   \   \   \ \mbox{ for all } \ x, y \in X.$$

Then is $X$ complete with respect to the norm induced by the above inner product?

I know that the space of all continuous functions is not complete in the above norm.

Let $x_m \colon= \sum_{j=0}^n \alpha_{jm} t^j$, where $t \in [a,b]$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$,  be a Cauchy sequence in $X$. Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N = N(\epsilon)$ such that 
$$\Vert x_m - x_k \Vert < \epsilon \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ m, k \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that } \ m > N \ \mbox{ and } \ k > N.$$
Or, 
$$\sqrt{\int_a^b \ \vert x_m(t) - x_k(t) \vert^2 \ \mathrm{d} t } < \epsilon \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ m, k \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that } \ m > N \ \mbox{ and } \ k > N.$$
That is, 
$$\sqrt{\int_a^b \ \left\vert \sum_{j=0}^n \left( \alpha_{jm} - \alpha_{jk} \right) \  t^j \ \right\vert^2  \ \mathrm{d} t } < \epsilon \ \ \ \mbox{ for all } \ m, k \in \mathbb{N} \ \mbox{ such that } \ m > N \ \mbox{ and } \ k > N.$$

What next?

Our aim should be to achieve the "Cauchy-ness" of the sequence $\alpha_{jm}$ of real or complex numbers, for each $j = 0, 1, \ldots, n$.

Am I right? If so, how to achieve this goal?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think one way to do the proof would be to see that your vector space is finite dimensional over a complete field and such vector spaces are complete (All norms are equivalent, so you it suffices to see this for the euclidean norm on $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @jorst yes I do know the following results: (1) On a finite-dimensional normed space, every norm is equivalent to every other norm. (2) Every finite-dimensional normed space is a Banach space. So this space is a Banach space, relative to every norm including the norm induced by the above inner product. Am I right?

Comment: yes, exactly. So this answers your question in the other comment as well: the inner product induced by the above may not be the euclidean one but the norms are equivalent and that is all you need.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168275/proof-that-every-finite-dimensional-normed-vector-space-is-complete, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42663/why-is-it-true-that-every-finite-dimensional-inner-product-space-is-a-hilbert-sp

Answer (score 0):

The vector space of all polynomials of degree at most $n$ is isomorphic with $\mathbb{R^{n+1}}$ and is complete for every natural number.

Comment: yes, these two spaces are isomorphic as vector spaces. But, are they also isomorphic as inner product spaces? That's the key question, you see.